# Gallery Block in template, validation fails after adding column number

Tags: block-editor, gallery, validation

I have set up a template in a block like so:

```
    const TEMPLATE = 
            ['core/spacer', {height: '100px'}],
            ['core/gallery', {templateLock: 'false', columns: 2}]
        ;
   const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps(
        blockProps,
        {template: TEMPLATE ,
        templateLock:"false"}
    );
    
        return (
            <>
                <div { ...innerblocksProps }>
         
                </div>
            </>
        );
```

The main reason is that I wanted a default column number of 2.
The `save.js` part:

```
const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps.save(blockProps);

    return (
        <div {...innerBlocksProps} />
);
```

All this works but whenever I reopen a post to change something, it says "Block validation failed", displaying this:

[image]

I have no idea where the `column-default` class is coming from. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: `column-default` is being generated by the gallery blocks save function, it's testing what was saved in the database against what the block has to see if it's valid or broken. This heavily implies there's attributes that are missing in your template that are still needed. Copying a gallery block shows a `linkTo` attribute. Also is your code complete? I see `useInnerBlocksProps.save()` but there is no call to `useInnerBlocksProps()` and the use of separate variables for each is not what the docs show, `blockProps` is normally passed into the `save` method of the inner props

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I rearranged the InnerBlockProps stuff. I missed that.

But the real issue was that I put `columns: '2'` instead of `columns: 2.` ... haha

Comment: can you edit your question to include that? As well as the complete save component? Is this your code or is it a sanitised version? And can you post your solution as an answer in the big box below? I can upvote an answer but you don't get points for comment upvotes and the site will keep suggesting the question to people!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Posted it as an answer, but says I can only mark it as solved by tomorrow which I'll do

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Toms reply I took a closer look again with fresh eyes and saw that I wrote `columns: '2'` instead of `columns: 2`. I also added the `linkTo: 'media'` attribute and rearranged the code to follow documentation (passing BlockProps to innerBlocksProps - I edited the original code post to reflect that).